# Is there a human-readable stack trace anywhere?

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I realise [the docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/errors/) talk about this, but my errors look nothing like that.

I'm using React and Apollo Server 2. Have not disabled debug, nor set the environment to production. All my errors are completely unreadable and say nothing useful at all, aside from the message itself. Example:

```
Error: GraphQL error: Cannot return null for non-nullable field AddSubmissionOutput.id.
    at new ApolloError (bundle.esm.js:76)
    at Object.next (bundle.esm.js:1280)
    at notifySubscription (Observable.js:152)
    at onNotify (Observable.js:196)
    at SubscriptionObserver.next (Observable.js:248)
    at bundle.esm.js:1085
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.next (bundle.esm.js:1084)
    at notifySubscription (Observable.js:152)
    at onNotify (Observable.js:196)
    at SubscriptionObserver.next (Observable.js:248)
    at Object.next (bundle.esm.js:32)
    at notifySubscription (Observable.js:152)
    at onNotify (Observable.js:196)
    at SubscriptionObserver.next (Observable.js:248)
    at bundle.esm.js:107
```

Every single error looks like this, and is essentially useless.

I'm used to Laravel, where it'd say the exact file and line of this error, rather than "go remove lines of code until you find it". I gave up on Apollo because it was all too cryptic, but I'm trying again and just can't get past this.

Am I expecting too much from it, or is something wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you throw an error inside your resolver (or inside some other module imported by your resolver), you'll see the appropriate stack trace. However, validation errors like the one above don't originate in your code base -- they are thrown inside the library code so the stack trace will reflect this. In this case, the error is related to response validation, but the same behavior would apply for bad queries as well.